# DDD: Ubiquitous language vs published language

Tags: domain-driven-design

To ask this question in the shortest way possible: can they be different?

Background: Vlad Khononov in his excellent book 'Learning Domain-Driven Design (2021)' writes (p55):

> The supplier's public interface is not intended to conform to its
> ubiquitous language. Instead, it is intended to expose a protocol
> convenient for the consumers, expressed in an integration-oriented
> language.
>
> In a sense, the open-host service pattern is a reversal of the anticorruption layer pattern:  instead of the consumer, the supplier implements
> the translation of its internal model.

Whereas, Olaf Zimmerman in a great article (2021) (https://eprints.cs.univie.ac.at/6948/1/europlop21-s16-camera-ready2.pdf) writes:

> But in order to make the API understandable to domain experts, it is
> essential that names and abstractions in the API follow the terms
> defined in the ubiqitous language which is formally specified by the
> domain model.

I think the anwer to question would be YES: it's possible to use different terms in published language and ubiquitous language for the same domain element. In the domain model you register the different terminology by applying 'aliases': an alias denotes the published language term used for an element in the domain model which is named according the ubiquitous language of the corresponsing bounded context.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

## Ubiquitous language

- Internally restricted and applied only within a specific Bounded Context. Will lose meaning in other Bounded Contexts.
- Commonly used by Domain Experts, Business Analysts, Engineers, etc. to communicate with each others under Bounded Context. Therefore, mainly expressed via human language writing/speaking (eg: English).

## Published language

- Publicly used to communicate (aka integrate) between different Bounded Contexts. Have agreed-meaning across Bounded Contexts.
- Mainly used by engineers working in different Bounded Contexts to agree on integration approach (open-host, client-server, pub-sub, etc.). Therefore, mainly expressed via technical format (API, JSON, XML, Protocol Buffer, etc.)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I have the same understanding. So Ubiqitous Language (UL) differs from Published Language (PL) and is used by different people. What about the translation between these two? Should every bounded context maintain a translation table that translates UL into PL and vice versa? See the concept of 'Alias' in the above question text.

Furhermore, I cannot find a the above definition of Published Language in the canonical literature on DDD (Evans, Vernon, Millet & Tune, Khononov). Can you guide me please to sources in DDD literature?

Answer (score 0):

The question is how much translation do Devs (internal and external) need to do between terms in the API vs. words in UL. It is almost always a trade-off, one that is shaped over time as the product and its API evolve.

All these patterns are acceptable and effective in their way:

1. A consumer-friendly API that at times deviates from UL
2. An API that reflects UL terms in APIs, ensuring internal and external stakeholders share the same view of the bounded context
3. A translation layer that maps the consumer-friendly external API to the internal UL terminology through aliases

Managing an external API means less wriggle room if you uncover terminology changes. Instead of trying to retain terms as-is, Approach 3 helps you improve the internal UL while still protecting the API sanctity.

You can start with Approach 2 by default and strive to retain it, but be open to being guided by external input and switch approaches.